# PHP run BASH script to add printers locally (OS X)

Tags: php, macos, bash

Thanks in advance for helping. I am trying to set up a public website for my organization which consist of all the organization's printers and the accompanying configurations (printer name, location details, SMB path and driver to use which is already provided by the OS X). From this web site a user will search for a printer and add/install the printer to their OS X workstation by clicking on a link.

I am looking at setting up a PHP site and the printer installation action facilitated by BASH script. Below are the codes:

This is the webSite.php

```
<?PHP
 exec("bash ./InstallPrinter.sh");
?>
```

and this is the InstallPrinter.sh BASH script

```
#!/bin/sh
lpadmin -p ToshibaPrinterName -L Location/Building/Level 1 -v smb://prin-server.AD.ORG/ToshibaEStudio4520C-A -P"/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/TOSHIBA_eS4520CSeries.gz"
cupsenable ToshibaPrinterName
/usr/sbin/accept ToshibaPrinterName
```

The printer will install but not locally on the workstation but on the server hosting the PHP and BASH script. I see the printer turn up in the OS X System Preferences, which is not the expected result. Is there a way to make the BASH script run it's command on the local workstation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. You will have to provide the shell script as a download and instruct the user on how to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant execute bash script on a local machine (for obvious reasons) and you also cant offer a bash script to download without having to change the CHMOD permissions to executable. I would suggest making applescript to add the printer and offering that to download.

Comment: "cant offer a bash script to download without having to change the CHMOD permissions to executable" Incorrect.

Comment: It is incorrect on... any system I can think of. The interpreter can always be passed the script.